# Parameter encoding with Micronaut HTTP client inside Grails 4

Tags: grails, grails-4, micronaut-client

In a Grails 4.0.1 app I'm using the Micronaut HTTP client to call an external web service. Parameters are automatically url encoded into UTF-8. How can I force the encoding to be Windows-1252 instead?